# beanstalkd storage backend

Tags: beanstalkd

I would like to know if thers any db storage for beanstalkd queue system
http://kr.github.com/beanstalkd/

My primany intention is to analyse the job status , completed or dumped or in process or done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [binary log](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/master/binlog.c) but that is designed to be transient, with logs discarded as they are finished with. The [stats](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/blob/v1.1/doc/protocol.txt) will give high-level information about how many jobs have been processed, being run by workers right now, and are yet to process, as well as removed, buried and more.

Beyond those numbers, it might be usful to generate some stats for yourself that aren't recorded by the daemon itself when a job is first queued, and/or after it has been reserved/deleted/completed/buried.

Comment: where can I find this bin log directory on mac??